# grammar in 他んとこにしてる借金

Tags: grammar, words, slang, sentence, structure

can anyone tell me how this sentence is working together?
The full sentence is
「この７万から 水道代を払って他んとこにしてる借金を払うと…」
I assume とこ is ところ used for "thing"? Or am I off?
or is he saying he has a debt he has taken, and the verb for taking a debt is "する"
Any ideas?

Comment: 「他のところに借金してる」means "have debt in other place" so「他のところにしてる借金」means other place’s debt...?

Answer (score 4):

As you guess, とこ is ところ, which means literally 'place' as commented.

In 他んところにしてる借金, 他んところにしてる is a relative clause modifying 借金. So it means *the debt (I) have at other places*. More concretely, ところ means money lenders.

Comment: Thank you! As you said here ところ　is also being used to describe a group of people. I actually saw this today in a video too, so suppose I must just adjust my ear to not think of ところ as a physical place, but also being able to mean certain groups of people?

Comment: @L.L. To some extent, yes, though it seems more or less naturally referring to place most of the time. This may make contrast to English where personal pronouns are used when it means a place (e.g. *call on her* to mean *visit her place*)